# Dragonboard 410c crashes just after bootup automatically

Tags: android, adb, boot, dragonboard

The `Dragonboard 410c` with the android crashes immediately after bootup. I tried the same thing with 2 different new dragonboards. In order to cross check, I again installed a new android through SD card but, issue still persists.

I wanted to run ADB commands through the dragonboard. 
Initially it used to crash after `ADB root` and `ADB reboot` commands and I had to disconnect and reconnect the adapter to start it again. But now it just flashes and then crashes even before I write the commands.

It would be a great help if someone can help me fix this thing and know the reason behind such indefinite crashes ?

P.S.: No such problems were there with the `201c module`.

Comment: Thanks, @rdj7 for remodeling the whole thing. It was silly on my part to make such Typos but yeah I have solved that problem. Earlier, I had pushed a script not compatible with the 'Dragonboard 410c'. and that the sole reason it used to crash. I had to reinstall the Android in it to fix the problem.